# Django Views: Is this the correct way to use the dispatch method of a Django class based view?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a class based view, and from the get and post request I have been calling a method, to obtain information from information in the HttpResponseRedirect kwargs.

code:

```
class View1(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... stuff ...

        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        ... stuff ...

        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('results:report_experiment',
            kwargs={
               'sample_id': current_sample_id
               }
             ))


class View2(CustomView):

    def obtainInformation(self, kwargs):

        sample_id = kwargs.get('sample_id', None)
        self.sample_obj = Sample.objects.get(id=sample_id)


    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        self.obtainInformation(kwargs)

        return super(View2, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... stuff ...

        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)



    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        ... stuff ...

        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('results:report_experiment',
            kwargs={
               'sample_id': current_sample_id
               }
             ))
```

My question is, when I call self.obtainInformation(kwargs) in the dispatch method, I can access any class variables I define in BOTH the get and post methods. Previously I was calling self.obtainInformation(kwargs) in both the get and post methods of view2 (so calling the method twice).

Is this a sensible way to use the dispatch method?

Comment: can you show us your obtainInformation function? not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: also: you should never return a render in a CBV, IF you need to do stuf in the get just return a `super(ViewName, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Hi, The obtainInformation method is to get information about the sample. I.e I use the sample_id to get a model object. This is a very simplified example, I actually get more information. I was just thinking, instead of calling this obtainInformation method twice (in GET and POST), I could call it once, (in DISPATCH) and then be able to access the self variables in both GET and POST

Comment: I realise now, that I am calling the method twice anyway- never mind! And I do not understand - why should I not return a render in CBV?

Comment: Yes I think that is a sensible solution if you need that information in both the get and the post. If you don't need them in both methods it will hit the database on every request and I would put it in only one of the methods. Have you looked into the other CBV? Create/Update/List/Delete ?

Comment: Sorry, that was actually not True for the basic View. All the other CBV will render the template for you, so no need to call render for those. You did it correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, overriding `dispatch()` as you have done looks ok, and prevents the duplication of having to call `obtainInformation` in `get()` and `post()`.

In Django 2.2+ there is a new [`setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.setup) method that you could use.

```
class View2(CustomView):

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.obtainInformation(kwargs)
```